# Combine pending and done in Jasmine test which uses Promises

Tags: javascript, jasmine, tdd

So I need to run a Jasmine test based on a specific condition which is returned by a promise, before running the test. Since there doesn't seem to be a way to exclude describes dynamically with Promises, I am checking the promise outcome and then either running some expects or just calling done(). This is not ideal because having a test just with `done()` results in `"SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS"`, but if I use `pending()` in the case the test shouldn't be run then the test fails as there is no `done()` being called within the timeout. 
My current implementation is (this function gets called from a describe with a specific `testing_case`) :

```
function checkOptions(testing_case) {
for (var key in cases_expectations[testing_case]) {
    (function (case, expectation) {
        it(case + " should be " + expectation, function (done){
            this.is.a.function.then(function(result) {
                var current_case = result.case;
                if (current_case !== testing_case) {
                    done();
                } else {
                    this.is.another.function(current).then(function(result) {
                        expect(result).toBe(expected);
                        done();
                    }, function(error) {
                        expect().toBeDefined();
                        done();
                    });
                }
            }, function(error) {
                expect().toBeDefined();
                done();
            });
        })  
    })(key, cases_expectations[testing_case][key]);
}
}
```

Two questions:

- How can I or can I combine `pending()` with `done()`?
- Is there a way to run describes within a promise?